# angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-demo with external drag-Elements

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I combined this [drag & drop demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-demo) with some external draggable elements. As you can see in the [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lknx6g), those external draggable elements are not able to be dropped into the major dropzone or even as a child inside. I´m new in Angular and tried several steps that ended in no result. First I think my draggable-elements need to be registered in the Array "allDropListsIds"...

Edit: The "onDragDrop"-function is not even fired, therefor I think the dropped-Element is not registered, because a placement as child hovers no green Dropcolor. You can try dragging around some existing elements.

It may be also an issue of the template as [connectedDropListsIds], [cdkDropListConnectedTo] may be used wrong.

It would be nice if anybody could give me some hints.

Regards, Dom

Answer (score 0):

In the angular website: [angula official docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) there is an example of how to make the feature you want, by using the angular/cdk component.

You will need to import in yout TS file:

```
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
```

And then use the event 'drop' triggered by your component to your own method and do something like this:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
}
```